# VS 2017 Text Editor for SQL items issue

Tags: visual-studio-2017, text-editor

I know there's **got** to be an option for this: I recently started using VS 2017 and now anytime I edit some SQL query, stored-proc, whatever, it automatically upper-cases a word after I type it in.  This is kinda' frustrating, as I want to turn that option off, assuming that there is an option to do so.

Anyone know where to find it?